# Email Images are not getting rendered.

Tags: c#, email, browser-cache

My emails have images that come from database.

So, when I change the images the Images that are shown on my email will change
but the problem is that the images that are displayed are still the old one.
But If I go into the DOM and copy the src of the image and paste it into the address bar the downloaded image is the new image.

Its like there is some sort of cache problem or something. So I cleared the system cache but the image rendered is still the old one

Answer (score 0):

Check these things
1. Server side - Are you clearing all the objects after sending the data to the client?
2. Client side - try by clearing the cache or Make sure you are having images with different names

Suggestion: Please update your question with client side and server side code so that we can guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a cache problem. In `.NET framework` there is a copy of the database which gets created at your end to fetch the data at runtime. Due to this you're not getting the updated images from the DB.

To get the updated images, make sure your code accesses the database and fetches the images EVERY-TIME you need.

The key is to get the data directly from the database before displaying.

Also, provide more details for better solutions.